# Wordpress: Understanding javascript-based post filters

Tags: javascript, wordpress, filter

I've been assigned with continuing to work on a WP-theme someone else has set up and I am still running into some problems, being very new to Wordpress.

I believe, one thing the person who worked on this before me did, is set up buttons at the top of the page which allow for sorting or restricting the posts displayed according to their respective categories. This is exactly what the user should be able to do, but it is not working yet and I'm having trouble understanding how to use the code my former colleague did write for this. This is the markup for the display of the site's posts, the script at the bottom is what I think is supposed to enable the filtering of the posts:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper-offset-fix wrapper-projekte">
<div class="projekte">

    <div class="button-group filters-button-group">
        <button class="active btn" id="all">alle</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-wise-201516">WiSe15/16</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-sose-15">SoSe15</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-wise-201415">WiSe14/15</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-sose-14">SoSe14</button>
    </div>


    <?php if (is_home()) {
    query_posts("cat=-3");
    } ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('large');
            } ?>
            </a>
        <!--<div class="meta">Tags: <?php the_tags( '', ', ', '<br />' ); ?> </div>-->
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2>Couldn’t find any articles!</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<script>
    var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {

      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('.projekte > .post').fadeIn(600);
      } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(600);
        $('.projekte > .post').not($el).hide();
      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It be incredibly helpful if someone could explain this to me and also help me with getting it to work. I'm definitely new to WP, php and JS but would really like to get a grasp on it. And of course get the site to work properly.

**EDIT**

Here's the javascript at the bottom of the page as a separate piece of code:

```
<script>
    var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {

      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('.projekte > .post').fadeIn(600);
      } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(600);
        $('.projekte > .post').not($el).hide();
      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

As far as I can tell there is no other JS linked to the page or executed in regards to the filter buttons. Here's also a link to the current version of the website which the code posted in my question is taken from: http://udkdev.skopec.de/category/projekte/

Comment: There has to be javascript somewhere... Can we see it?

Comment: @Salketer I posted the javascript found in the page itself below the question as a separate piece of code, beside that I can't find any, but I have also added the link to the online version of the website, maybe this helps. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the javascript binds the click event on elements with class "btn" but only your "all" button has that class. So it looks as if it does nothing.

Either change the buttons class, or the click target.

Comment: Completely fixed my problem, the script itself works fine, merely the class was missing from the buttons. Thanks for helping me out.